# Remove the automatically started apps on Mac

Tags: macos, boot

I've used "**sudo jamf removeframework**" to remove MDM.

But there is the McAfee icon stay on the status bar after booting the Mac as follows:

[image]

I typed the following commands to find the McAfee related files and find out some are displayed in red color.

```
ls /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep mcaf
```

[image]

May I delete those fils whose color is red?

And the **com.mcafee.virusscan.fmpd.plist** and **com.mcafee.aac.plist** are empty files. Can I delete them?

Comment: McAfee has a proper uninstaller in the Apps folder. Your command to remove jamf was wrong. Any MDM manager with any clue will also have routines buried to put it back if you remove it. You should ask your IT department if you want to be released from any MDM, not DIY it.

Comment: Hi, the McAfee is installed with MDM, now the device profiles from company are deleted. But McAfee is not removed completely. Can we use CleanMyMac to clean it? Or it needs IT to clean it?

Comment: Hi, the McAfee is installed with MDM, now the device profiles from my company are deleted via the "sudo jamf removeframework" from IT. But McAfee is not removed completely. Can we use CleanMyMac to clean it? Or it needs IT to clean it?